# Strange Class-Not-Found-Exception with ClusterActorRefProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, akka, akka-cluster

I have a strange behaviour of my little akka cluster projekt:
I have a very simple application.conf:

```
akka {
    # specifiy logger
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    stdout-loglevel = "DEBUG"

    # configure remote connection
    actor {
        provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transport = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
        netty.tcp {
             hostname = "127.0.0.1"
             port = 3100
         }
     }
     cluster {
         seed-nodes = [
             "akka.tcp://mycluster@127.0.0.1:3100"
         ]
     }
}
```

And a very simple main program:

```
public class MediatorNodeStartup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String port = System.getProperty("config.port") == null ? "3100" :     System.getProperty("config.port");
        Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=" + port)
            .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("mycluster", config);
    }
 }
```

Akka, Akka-Remote and Akka-Cluster are all included via maven and visible in the class path.
Now when I execute this, it just fails with a ClassNotFoundException: akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider
although the akka.cluster.* package definitely is in my classpath.

Strangely enough, on another machine this code just works.
So I suppose it has something to do with my eclipse or runtime configuration... but sadly I have no idea where to start searching for the error.
Any ideas? I will provide further information if necessary.

Comment: Do you have the right version? Maybe you miss an update or something.

Comment: At least it looks like I do. Jar names are fine.

Comment: Did you take a look in the jar file? Did you manualy search for the  missing class?

Comment: The class is indeed in there. A problem is (that is why I have tagged that with akka) that the akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider is an internal class of akka and not visible to the akka user, therefor it is package private and I have no way of referencing it from outside. But it is this internal code at ActorSystem.create that fails...